# Running Groovy Script with Highscale lib causes SecurityException

Tags: java, groovy

While running a groovy script I get this exception:

```
Caught: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.util.concurrent
```

I noticed a library in my classpath `high-scale-lib-1.0.6.jar` which has a class `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.class` in the library.

I need this library so what can I do to get groovy scripts running? I read something about whitelists for such cases.

Any ideas on how I could solve this issue ?